# Maven doesn't download the dependencies and unable to import the packages

Tags: selenium, maven, pom.xml

I have imported a repository from Bitbucket to my local in eclipse. Though all the necessary dependencies are added in the pom.xml files, the dependencies are not downloaded & the error is shown in the pom.xml file (in the icon, not in any of the dependencies in the file). And I'm unable to import the required packages.

Could anyone tell me what exactly is the issue in here?

Comment: Share your code and the error you got please...

Comment: This usually means the repository is not reachable. Check if you are using maven central or a locally / enterprise maven repository. If it is later then ensure the repository is accessible or you need a VPN

Comment: I have imported a copy of it in eclipse, Rahul. Usually it should work when we add any dependency.

Comment: It's work related @Tal and I'm afraid I'm not allowed to share. I just get "Missing artifact" in the overview of pom.xml. But I checked the dependencies and it's same as in Maven Repository!.

Comment: Run `mvn clean verify` and report the errors you get.

Comment: There were some duplicate dependencies... And I've removed it mate. But still, import package option is not displayed in the class files though we have added the respective dependencies.

Comment: Update: I get the below:
```Failed to execute goal on project ACB: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.acats.acb:ACB:jar:1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.acats.core:ACATS:jar:2.8.8: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.acats.core:ACATS:jar:2.8.8: Could not transfer artifact com.acats.core:ACATS:pom:2.8.8 from/to you-snapshots (http://host/nexus/repos/snapshots): host -> [Help 1]
```